# US resident UK passport

Tags: usa, uk-citizens, biometric-passports

I am a US resident alien on a valid "green card". My UK passport expires on March 04 2024. If I go on holiday outside USA, will I need the new bio-metric UK passport to re-enter the USA?

Comment: The biometric passport requirement applies to visa waiver program participants. You are not a VWP participant.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a passport to reenter the US, for trips of less than 6 months you [only need your green card](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/~/traveling-outside-of-the-u.s.---documents-needed-for-lawful-permanent-residents). The passport may be required by by the countries you travel to, so only their requirements matter.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted/international-travel-permanent-resident:

> If seeking to enter the United States after temporary travel abroad, you will need to present a valid, unexpired “green card” (Form I-551, Permanent Resident Card). When arriving at a port of entry, a U.S. Customs and Border Protection Officer will review your permanent resident card and any other identity documents you present, such as a passport, foreign national I.D. card or U.S. Driver’s License, and determine if you can enter the United States.

So short answer: you don't need the UK passport specifically to help establish that you are the person for whom the green card was issued, but the UK passport is an option.

Somewhat related: the US does frown on dual citizens using a foreign passport to enter or leave the US (https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-and-dual-nationality/dual-nationality.html):

> Most U.S. nationals, including dual nationals, must use a U.S. passport to enter and leave the United States. Dual nationals may also be required by the foreign country to use its passport to enter and leave that country.

Summary: the green card and some photo ID is sufficient.  In light of the US's attitude to its citizens (which of course are distinct from permanent residents) entering on foreign passports, I'd probably consider showing the UK passport to be the last resort.

Comment: Do you really mean "last resort" to apply to USA resident UK citizens? I've used the combination of green card and UK passport to enter the USA many, many times over the last 30+ years.

Comment: I have no direct experience with this but I understand that LPRs arriving by air will generally be asked to show their passports even though these are not required for entry, as @PatriciaShanahan's comment suggests, which is why they mention "any other identity documents." The green card is itself an identity document, after all, and suffices by itself to identify the bearer. Additional photo ID is not required.